# Why does git pull sometimes fail, but a second git pull always succeeds?

Tags: git

Not asking about a specific scenario, more in general. When I start up my workstation and am updating repos at the start of a day, often I get sporadic git failures even though my network and filesystem is ready and initialized, like this:

```
git pull
code .fatal: Cannot fast-forward to multiple branches.
```

Repeating the command with `!!` succeeds and fetches all the changes I expect.

Other days, I see messages like:

```
$ git pull
code .error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': is at fcc8a3211e4a701d7fa99362fd764dd102232def but expected ea150ba4eba738a7864a9ce812d938d1879af4fd
From code.fancypants.internal.domain:user/my-cool-repo
 ! ea150ba4e..fcc8a3211  master         -> origin/master  (unable to update local ref)
 * [new branch]          jira/TICKET-111 -> origin/jira/TICKET-111
```

and again, a `!!` or `git pull` and it succeeds:

```
$ git pull
Updating ea150ba4e..fcc8a3211
Fast-forward
...
```

What is the purpose of these failure messages when the command succeeds the second time? Am I as a user expected to take some action? Should I alias `git pull` to `/usr/bin/git pull $@ || /usr/bin/git pull $@`? Are these messages just "pieces of flair"?

Environment:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.34.1

$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
```

Comment: Both errors mean something else is syncing git **while** you attempt to pull. Github desktop or VSCode commonly auto-sync for example, and it makes sense that it happens as you are starting up.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale I do have the git bash prompt installed - is this likely a culprit? https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt

If so - is there a "correct" way to detect this and wait?

Comment: I'm not sure - probably not if it's only checking the git status, but I did find this question where someone mentions their bash-git-prompt does automatic fetching in the background (and some other troubleshooting steps in the comments): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72110191/what-is-causing-cannot-fast-forward-to-multiple-branches-during-git-pull. As far as how to tell, I think you just want to check for a lock file (`.git/index.lock`?) before pulling

Comment: https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt/issues/523